# W3 Total Cache doesn't work fine in multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

I have installed W3 Total Cache for multisite. The current site is using a child theme of Genesis framework.

I enable the option `Does not cache for logged in users`, set the cache time to 300s and begin testing as guest for the home page.

The problem is that the site does not servered the lastest cached page. When visiting the home page, it servers the page that cached from some hours ago. I try to view the page source to check the time W3TC generates and realize that the result is very different from different browsers:

IE: `Served from: bem.vn @ 2013-10-17 17:33:45 by W3 Total Cache -->`
FF: `Served from: bem.vn @ 2013-10-18 09:59:53 by W3 Total Cache -->`

Then I check the lastest cached page of home page in the `wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/bem.vn/httq` directory, the result is:
`Served from: bem.vn @ 2013-10-18 21:18:53 by W3 Total Cache -->`

I don't know why the result is that. Could anyone give me some suggestions?